# Should I be making this a model?

Tags: php, zend-framework, models

I have a family of complex select queries which I need to call from different parts of the application.  I think I should group them all into a model class, but would like to verify this.

The queries all work off the same set of 5 tables.  Each of these tables has its own Table Data Gateway class and Row Data Gateway class, but my new class for the queries would not be implementing any such pattern (since it doesn't wrap a table or row).  My new class would be calling on the Table and Row Data Gateways already established.

In addition, the values that come from users can't be susbstituted into the queries directly, so I plan to do some pre-processing in the new class as well.  This pre-processing includes accessing the DB for lookup values, etc.

Does this sound fair?  I think it's exactly how models should be used, but I can be spectacularly wrong about such things so would appreciate any comments or advice.  (FYI, I'm using Zend Framework).

Comment: Yes, this belongs to the Persistence Layer in the Model. Apart from that, there isnt much to say about it without knowing what that new class is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries don't go in the Model part. They are persistence related (the model doesn't handle persistence).

These complex queries should be in the Persistence layer, which is here the Table Data Gateway classes.

I would name the Table Data Gateway classes "DAO" (Data Access Object). A Table Data Gateway is a kind of DAO, since you can have a DAO that help you get things from files, webservices...

So you can keep your actual classes, and add a DAO to manage these complex queries. **This DAO is not providing you access to a specific DB table, but it is still providing you access to a data source (composed by several DB tables).**

**Edit :**

I suggest you to create a **DAO** `interface` (it may be empty). You DB Tables will implement this interface. Your new class will also implement this interface, but not extend `Zend_Db_Table`.

In short, you are redefining/renaming your persistence layer, from "Zend Db Table" to "DAO" (which makes it more generic). Zend Db Table is a *kind* of DAO.

Comment: The Persistence Layer is one layer (among many) in the Model.

Comment: When I'm using the word "Model", I'm talking about the "Domain model". Persistence is indeed in the "Model", but as the OP is asking "Should I be making this a model ?", I'm just using the same name (he uses "model" to differentiate from his Table Data Gateway classes).

Comment: Hi Matthieu.  So, are you saying my queries belong in the DB Table classes?

Comment: Yes, but not only. I'm saying your DB Table classes *are* DAO classes (this is just a naming convention). *But* if you have queries on multiple tables, you can create a new DAO class, which won't be a DB Table because it won't be related to a specific table, but this class will also be a DAO class. I am then suggesting you to extend the naming of your persistence layer (you are actually naming it "Table Data Gateway" or "DB Table", I suggest to name it DAO) so that it can be more generic and include DAO that are not extending the Zend DB table class.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain more what you can do in your code.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, very much appreciated.